# Are all elementary massive particles distortions in the Higgs field?

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs, elementary-particles

I am confused, as I understand it, all elementary massive particles are sourcing from the Higgs scalar field thus are all distortions in the Higgs field. How this differs elementary from the old historic concept of an absolute medium in the Universe?

Comment: I vote to keep open because although the first sentence is rather confused, the second sentence asks a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our best model of the physical world at the moment is the one proposed by quantum field theory and by research programmes related to this, such as string theory. The term 'Standard Model' is used as a shorthand to refer to the description in its most tested form. In such models, there is, everywhere through the universe, and through all of time, a set of *quantum fields*. Quantum fields are subtle things. Certain types of energetic excitations of these fields correspond to what we call particles of matter and of light. The Higgs field is one of these fields, but it is not the only one. The electromagnetic field is another. It might be possible to describe them all as different aspects of a single more complicated kind of field.

Since these fields are everywhere, they could be described as a kind of 'medium' but it is a special kind of 'medium' because there is no experimental method, even in principle, that could tell whether you are moving relative to such a 'medium'. This is why it is not completely like the historic idea of a medium called aether. But in  some respects it is reminiscent of that idea. After all, the electromagnetic field can contain energy and deliver momentum, so it has these kinds of physical properties, and so do all the other fields of the Standard Model. So this is sort of like an aether, but one described by relativistic mechanics not Newtonian mechanics, and also, in complete detail, by quantum mechanics not classical mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

An [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) belongs to the standard model table of elementary particles.

[image: elempart]

Please note all the quantum numbers characterizing each entry on the table, and note that the mass, even though it is a unique number, is not included as crucial to the definition of the particle.

> as I understand it, all elementary massive particles are sourcing from the Higgs scalar field thus are all distortions in the Higgs field.

Their mass is induced by the Higgs field and the [Higgs mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism), indirectly, but the symmetries obeyed and modeled with the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), and their individuality are not due to the higgs field.